# Not sure how to approach this with a mySQL query for two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `users` and `distance`. In a page I need to list all users with a simple query such as `select * from users where active=1 order by id desc`.

Sometimes I need to output data from the `distance` table along with this query where the user ID field in `users` is matched in the `distance` table in EITHER of two columns, say `userID_1` and `userID_2`. Also in the `distance` table either of the two mentioned columns must also match a specified id (`$userID`) as well in the where clause.

This is the best that I came up with:

```
select 
    a.*,
    b.distance 
from 
    users a,
    distance b 
where 
    ((b.userID_1='$userID' and a.id=b.userID_2) 
  or (a.id=b.userID_1 and b.userID_2='$userID')) 
 and a.active=1 
order by a.id desc
```

The only problem with this query is that if there is no entry in the `distance` table for the where clause to find a match, the query does not return anything at all. I still want it to return the row from the `user` table and return `distance` as null if there are no matches.

I cannot figure out if I need to use a JOIN, UNION, SUBQUERY or anything else for this situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a left join between 'users' and 'distance'. As a result (pun not intended), you will always get the rows from the 'users' table along with any matching rows (if any) from 'distance'.

I notice that you are using the SQL-89 join syntax ("implicit joins") as opposed to SQL-92 join syntax ("explicit joins"). I wrote about this [once](http://www.nbnewman.blogspot.co.il/2011/08/implicit-vs-explicit-joins-sql.html).

I suggest that you change your query to

```
select a.*, b.distance 
from users a left join distance b 
on ((b.userID_1='$userID' and a.id=b.userID_2) 
or (a.id=b.userID_1 and b.userID_2='$userID')) 
where a.active=1 
order by a.id desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a left join

```
select 
    a.*,
    b.distance 
from 
    users a
    left join distance b on
       (b.userID_1=? and a.id=b.userID_2) 
    or (b.userID_2=? and a.id=b.userID_1)
where 
    a.active=1 
order by a.id desc
```

and use a prepared statement. Substituting text into a query is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.*, b.distance 
from users a 
left join distance b on (a.id=b.userID_1 or a.id=b.userID_2) and 
                        (b.userID_1 = '$userID' or b.userID_2 = '$userID') 
where a.active=1 
order by a.id desc
```